# Why is it necessary for the standard enthalpy of fusion to change at the transition temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics, enthalpy

I have a table here:

[image]

For argon, for example, shouldn't the standard enthalpy of fusion @ 83.81K be 0 J/mol?

After all, it is already at the respective transition temperature.

Comment: The question in title does not make much sense. At fusion transition T, what is changing is enthalpy, not enthalpy of fusion (which is not zero)

Answer (score 3):

It is not the *enthalpy* change that goes to zero at phase equilibrium, but the *free energy* change. And that involves entropy as well as enthalpy.

What happens is this: the "higher" phase -- liquid over solid, vapour over liquid -- embodies more disorder and thus more entropy, so the Second Law allows it to form with a loss of entropy in the surroundings -- meaning heat energy flows from the surroundings into the melting or boiling material. Then the First Law dictates that at constant pressure, which is the case in an equilibrium process, enthalpy goes up. Ergo a positive enthalpy change with melting or boiling even as the free energy change is zero.